Adjusting GridLayout Order in Qt Designer?
I currenly want to make a window like this. The widgets are labelled in the picture.

The problem is I want to swap the locations of QTreeView and QFrame. I know hard coding the orders is possible, but I just want to know if there is a way in Qt Designer to set the order.

Just drag and drop the frame to where you need it.
